# Create and put a map value only if not already present, and get it: thread-safe implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, dictionary

What is the best way to make this snippet thread-safe?

```java
private static final Map<A, B> MAP = new HashMap<A, B>();

public static B putIfNeededAndGet(A key) {
    B value = MAP.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        value = buildB(...);
        MAP.put(key, value);
    }
    return value;
}

private static B buildB(...) {
    // business, can be quite long
}
```

Here are the few solutions I could think about:

1. I could use a `ConcurrentHashMap`, but if I well understood, it *just* makes the atomic `put` and `get` operations thread-safe, i.e. it does not ensure the `buildB()` method to be called only once for a given value.
2. I could use `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<A, B>())`, but I would have the same issue as the first point.
3. I could set the whole `putIfNeededAndGet()` method `synchronized`, but I can have really many threads accessing this method together, so it could be quite expensive.
4. I could use the double-checked locking pattern, but there is still the related [out-of-order writes issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11195509/1225328).

What other solutions may I have?

I know this is a quite common topic on the Web, but I didn't find a clear, full and working example yet.

Comment: What is your main concern? That `buildB()` may get called twice?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov Yes. Well, it can happen, but as seldom as possible ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the answer you're looking for, but use the [Guava](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) [`CacheBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html), it already does all that and more:

```
private static final LoadingCache<A, B> CACHE = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .maximumSize(100) // if necessary
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<A, B>() {
         public B load(A key) {
           return buildB(key);
         }
       });
```

You can also easily add timed expiration and other features as well.

This cache will ensure that `load()` (or in your case `buildB`) will not be called concurrently with the same `key`. If one thread is already building a `B`, then any other caller will just wait for that thread.

Comment: Well, this is actually exactly what I'm needing, since I planned to use a WeakHashMap. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 5):

Use ConcurrentHashMap and the lazy init pattern which you used

```
public static B putIfNeededAndGet(A key) {
    B value = map.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        value = buildB(...);
        B oldValue = map.putIfAbsent(key, value);
        if (oldValue != null) {
             value = oldValue;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: +1. I would not over-engineer and keep it simple. The worst thing that can happen in this scenario is that `buildB()` will get called several times.

Answer (score 2):

In the above solution it is possible that many threads will class `processB(...)` simultaneously hence all will calculate. But in my case i am using `Future` and a single thread only get the old value as `null` hence it will only compute the `processB` rest will wait on `f.get()`.

```
 private static final ConcurrentMap<A, Future<B>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<A, Future<B>>();
public static B putIfNeededAndGet(A key) {
    while (true) {
        Future<V> f = map.get(key);
        if (f == null) {
            Callable<B> eval = new Callable<V>() {
                public B call() throws InterruptedException {
                    return buildB(...);
                }
            };
            FutureTask<V> ft = new FutureTask<V>(eval);
            f = map.putIfAbsent(arg, ft);
            if (f == null) {
                f = ft;
                ft.run();
            }
        }
        try {
            return f.get();
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
            cache.remove(arg, f);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 - This solution handles both of the problems with this scenario - thread safety and once-only building.

Answer (score 1):

Thought maybe this will be useful for someone else as well, using java 8 lambdas I created this function which worked great for me:

```
private <T> T getOrCreate(Object key, Map<Object, T> map,
                                Function<Object, T> creationFunction) {
    T value = map.get(key);

    // if the doesn't exist yet - create and add it
    if (value == null) {
        value = creationFunction.apply(key);
        map.put(label, metric);
    }
    return value;
}
```

then you can use it like this:

```
Object o = getOrCreate(key, map, s -> createSpecialObjectWithKey(key));
```

I created this for something specific but changed the context and code to a more general look, that is why my creationFunction has one parameter, it can also have no parameters...

also you can generify it more by changing Object to a generic type, if it's not clear let me know and I'll add another example.

**UPDATE:**

I just found out about Map.computeIfAbsent which basically does the same, gotta love java 8 :)